# boto3.session.client('mediastore-data' ...) takes more than 2 seconds on EC2 instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, performance, boto3

here's what my python code does: 64 python threads are created, and each and every one of them performs the following:

1. create a boto3.session using explicit key id, secret, and token.
2. use endpoint_url from the cache (unless u're the 1st thread that is created. in this case, ask for the endpoint url using describe_container request. a request that performs once since endpoint urls are valid as long as the container lives).
3. using the boto3session created on (1), call boto3.session.client('mediastore-data', region=..., endpoint_url=..., config=botocore.config.Config(max_pool_connections = 64, parameter_validation = False))
4. in a loop, pop a job from an input Q and use the client created on (3) to call put_obejct requests.

i can measure item 3, and see it takes longer than 2 seconds when running on EC2. always.

moreover, i ran with tcpdump, in order to understand if the time goes on dns resolution or on the handshake, but i saw that those took reasonable times, and surely much under 2 seconds.

i use milliseconds granularity (and the tcpdump has micros), so i can also tell that the 1st dns query came AFTER the client was created, and that it's a result of the put_object() and not of the client creation.

versions: botocore 1.18.18 and boto3 1.15.6

Here's the code:

```
    # both session and client MUST be per thread
    # ==> they're not shared
    with AutoCheckpoint(f'MediaStoreStorage __init__ session on {millisnow()}', ilog):
        self.session = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id = info.s3_key,
            aws_secret_access_key = info.s3_secret,
            aws_session_token = info.s3_token
        )

    # get endpoint url from cache or request for it.
    with AutoCheckpoint(f'MediaStoreStorage __init__ sessiget_endpoint_url on {millisnow()}', ilog):
        self.endpoint = msstorage.MsStorage.get_endpoint_url(self.session, self.bucket_name, info.region)

    # build the mediastore data client using the endpoint url
    with AutoCheckpoint(f'MediaStoreStorage __init__ client on {millisnow()}', ilog):
        self.data_client = self.session.client(
            'mediastore-data',
            region_name = info.region,
            endpoint_url = self.endpoint,
            config = botocore.config.Config(max_pool_connections = 64, parameter_validation = False)
        )
```

(AutoCheckpoint is an object that measures (and reports) the time between its **enter** and **exit**)

Comment: What is the source code?

Comment: code added, thank u